# iPhone Storyboard Push is Slow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios5, storyboard

I have a storyboard setup in Xcode for my iPhone app and the first view which loads is a UINavigationController and then from its first view controller I have a button which in Interface Builder I simply connected it to a second view controller. I have a couple of UIImageViews and a UILabel in it, but there is very little going on.

My issue being, when I test this on my device (iPhone 4) and I tap that button it takes a good 3-4 seconds to load this new view.

Hope you can resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: How and when do you load the images for the UIImageViews?

Comment: check for any Over Allocations, leaks and use instruments Time Profiler check where it takes time to load ?!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the images that you are loading in the second VC and notice the duration.

Just in case, try very small size images to know if there is any issue.

Comment: Dear Kavish, please notice people's edits of your posts and learn from them. It's disheartening to have to fix each and every post of yours. Thank you.

Comment: RegDwight : I guess your'r the only one to edit the posts uptil now . Can you pl share the corrections that need to be made , so that i do not repeat the same .

Comment: Sure. Just check the edits by clicking on the timestamp link. Then you will see what changes have been made to your posts. E.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12195602/revisions). Note that some changes are not easily visible, such as the deleted white spaces before punctuation marks. (In English, the whitespace goes before the comma, period, etc., never after it.) Cheers.

Comment: Wow, turned out to be perfect for me. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

try to set all your data in

```
viewDidAppear
```

don't put in

```
viewWillAppear or in ViewDidLoad
```

Hope This will solve your issue.